# Login simulator in c, dereferencing incomplete types errors

Tags: c, unix, pointers, authentication

As a preporatory task for a computer lab in school, we are asked to write a c program that simulates the login process in UNIX. The program should read username and password from a terminal, compare it to hashed values in a local file that is supposed to resemble /etc/passwd.

Here's what I've got:

```
/*
 * Program mylogin.c
 *
 * This program prompts the user for a login name and password
 *
 */

#define _XOPEN_SOURCE
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pwd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <string.h>

/* define some error constants */
#define NOUSER -1

/* define max size of a username */
#define USERNAME_SIZE 32
#define PASSWORD_SIZE 32
#define HASH_SIZE 32
#define FAILED_LIMIT 5
#define AGE_LIMIT 10

int read_username(char *username)
{

    printf("login: ");
    fgets(username,USERNAME_SIZE,stdin);

    /* remove the CR included by getline() */
    username[strlen(username)-1]='\0';
    return(0);
}

int read_password(char *password)
{

    printf("password: ");
    fgets(password,PASSWORD_SIZE,stdin);
    //getpass(password);

    /* remove the CR included by getline() */
    password[strlen(password)-1]='\0';
    return(0);
}

int user_exists(const char *username)
{
    struct pwdb_passwd *pw_entry;

    pw_entry=getpwnam(username);
    return((pw_entry)!=NULL);
}

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    char username[USERNAME_SIZE];
    char* password;

    /* write "login:" and read user input */
    read_username(username);
    read_password(password);

    if (!user_exists(username))
    {
        printf("Unknown user or authentication\n");
        main(argc, argv);
    }
    struct pwdb_passwd *pw_entry = getpwnam(username);
    char* hashed_password = crypt(password,pw_entry->pw_passwd);
    if(strcmp(hashed_password,  pw_entry->pw_passwd)==0)
    {
        if((pw_entry->pw_failed)<FAILED_LIMIT)
        {
            printf("User authenticated successfully\n");
            pw_entry->pw_age++;
            pw_entry->pw_failed = 0;
            pwdb_update_user(pw_entry);
        }else{
            printf("User account locked\n");
            main(argc, argv);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Unknown user or authentication\n");
        pw_entry->pw_failed++;
        if(pw_entry->pw_failed>5){
            printf("Too many failed attempts. Username now locked\n");
        }
        pwdb_update_user(pw_entry);
        main(argc, argv);
    }
    return(0);
}
```

The struct pwdb_passwd is defined in the files pwdb_lib.c and pwdb_lib.h, which are already written.

When I compile the program, I get a couple of errors. For example on line 73, I get: "error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type"

I don't understand why. It doesn't seem to like `pw_entry->pw_passwd` and things like that. More to the point, I get different errors when compiling under Windows with Code::Blocks (using gcc) than under Ubuntu with gcc. I find this pretty strange. I suspect it could be because I import pwd.h and that it only exists on Linux and not Windows. Could this be right? I tried creating my own pwd.h file and save it in the same directory, but it still didn't work. Moving to an ubuntu computer, I dont get errors from the pwd.h thing, but instead get errors on: "dereferencing pointer to incomplete type"

What's wrong with my code?

I also suspect memory leak in the user_exists function, but I'm not sure if it affects the overall program.

Comment: Are you sure the type of `pw_entry` is correct?  `<pwd.h>` shows `getpwnam` returning `passwd*`

Comment: Here's the line I use to compile it under gcc. Maybe I need to include more libraries or something.

gcc -Wall -g -o login pwdblib.h pwdblib.c mylogin.c -lcrypt

Comment: Ah, this might be it. It should probably be pwdb_getpwnam, which is the name of the function in pwdb_lib.h. I will try it and come back in a couple of minutes :)

Comment: Yep, I tried including pwdb_lib.h instead of pwd.h and now things work a lot better. Only problem is now I get a warning on the 4th line of the main method.

It doesn't like the read_password(password); line "warning: ‘password’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]" but it's supposed to be unitialized because it get's it value in read_password. Is anything wrong in the code or should I just ignore it?

Comment: @user1661303 You should worry about that warning. You should allocate memory for `password` before passing it to `read_password`. Probably it's best to make `password` an array, like `username`. Also, `password[strlen(password)-1] = '\0';` needs a check that a) the length isn't 0, and, more likely to happen, although probably rare, b) that there is actually a newline, and the password entered is less than 31 characters long (and if the password is too long, you should think how to deal with that).

Answer (score 1):

Even though `pwdb_lib.c` is already written, you need to include it in your source file.

Add

```
#include "pwdb_lib.h"
```

to your source and make sure you compile/link against `pwdb_lib.c`

By `#include`ing this file, you let your source file know about the definitions within it without providing it the implementation. At the end, when you compile your program with `pwdb_lib.c` (or link its object file, if that's what you're doing), you let any source which included these definitions know where they are implemented (and thus, give them the ability to use them).

Comment: exactly what am I supposed to write in the terminal when I compile this? right now I link to crypt. should I also link to functions like getpass if I want to use them? I use a lot of functions that isnt written by me. I'm not really sure if I should link to them, include them or compile with them or all of the above. I use stuff like strcmp and I don't have to link to them.

I guess its because I include a standard library and its included there, but crypt and getpass is a system function.But sometimes if u  include a lot of libraries its hard to know whats in a library and whats a system func

Comment: `strcmp` and such are functions provided by the C standard library (it is automatically linked against). These other ones you will need to.

Answer (score 1):

If the header is named `pwdb_lib.h`, then why isn't your program doing an `#include` of it? It seems to include a different header (`pwd.h`), which is it?

The error you're getting is the one you'd expect if the declarations were missing.

Comment: OK, I'm not really sure about these include things. Do I always need to include something if it is in the same folder? And do I need to include both the header and c-file if it's split in two? And when I compile it, do I need to include every file that it is linked to in the gcc-line?

I probably had pwd.h earlier because it was needed in a previous part of the lab, but you're right, it shouldn't be needed anymore.

Comment: I tried including pwdb_lib, and now the program compiles, with a warning on line 65. When I run it, however, I get a segmentation fault (after typing username and password)